# The specified Cast is not a valid

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I would appreciate some help debugging this please. I have a stored proc as defined below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProcessBoxNumberPaymentInfo_Test]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @boxNumber int, 
     @ProcessDate DateTime,
     @BoxType Varchar(50),
     @PaymentProcessDate DateTime,
     @Identity int OUTPUT  

BEGIN 
    Declare @NewID as int 
  -- INSERT CODE GOES HERE

   Set @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  -- ANOTHER INSERT CODE GOES HERE
       SELECT @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  

END
```

On the code side, I have the following method in my DataContext class to execute my storedproc, passing the valids specified.

```
 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.usp_ProcessBoxNumberPaymentInfo_Test")]
        public int GetValidPaymentBoxNumberLogID_Test(
            [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "boxNumber", DbType = "Int")] string boxNumber,
            [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "ProcessDate", DbType = "DateTime")] DateTime ProcessDate,
            [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "BoxType", DbType = "VarChar(50)")] string BoxType,
            [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "PaymentProcessDate", DbType = "DateTime")] DateTime PaymentProcessDate,
            [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "Identity", DbType = "Int")] ref System.Nullable<int> identity)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), boxNumber, ProcessDate, BoxType, PaymentProcessDate, identity);
            identity = ((System.Nullable<int>)(result.GetParameterValue(4)));
            return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

Problem I am having is when I run the code, I get the following exception

**The specified Cast is not a valid**

This error is thrown at line **return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));**  I am not entirely sure what type is missing and where. Really, any help figuring this out will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it helps others if you declare which type of `Exception` you get and in what line it is thrown.

Comment: could this line be the problem `[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "boxNumber", DbType = "Int")] string boxNumber` also looking at it again I think this is where you are getting your `Casting` Error `IExecuteResult` you're trying to return `((int)result.ReturnValue))` is `IExecuteResult` returns an int but it looks like you're problem may be in the boxnumber datatype.

Comment: I believe the problem is in accessing the returned value for identity

Comment: Try putting a break point on the `return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));` line and see what result.ReturnValue actually is before trying the cast through a watch window.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not actually returning a value from your proc.  So `result.ReturnValue` won't actually contain anything.  If you're trying to access `identity`, wouldn't you already have that from the prior line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use here Unboxing:

```
return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
```

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Shoul be

```
return ((Int32.Parse(result.ReturnValue));
```

But if the result.ReturnValue is null it also will throw an exception.

safer

```
int a=0;
Int32.TryParse(result.ReturnValue, out a);
return a;
```

or check result.ReturnValue for nulls explicitly

Answer (score 0):

`(Name = "boxNumber", DbType = "Int")] string boxNumber`

Looks like you're trying to cast a string as an int?

Comment: That does not seem to be the problem. The error occurs at the line return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));

Answer (score 0):

When you call the store procedure try this:

```
ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> tmp;

tmp = GetValidPaymentBoxNumberLogID_Test (...

int identity = Convert.ToInt32(tmp.FirstOrDefault());
```

or just

```
int identity = Convert.ToInt32(GetValidPaymentBoxNumberLogID_Test (...).FirstOrDefault());
```